# How to ask for updated answers to a question already asked without posting a duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just spent the last hour looking for a solution to a question I had, and after a bunch of browsing I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138639/css-tables-invert-order-of-displayed-content). The question has an accepted answer which works from what I've tested, but four years later, there may be a better answer.

The answer abuses the css directional property, so I'd rather find a better way (if there is a better way), but I'm not sure posting the same question is the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way i know is to offer a bounty on the existing question and include the reason the already posted answers do not suit you and what you what.

Comment: Indeed, this is _the_ way to do it. One of the reasons one can use when placing a bounty is "**Current answers are outdated** The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes."

Comment: This has a sort of inequity, though, since brand-new users can't place bounties (as they don't have any rep yet).  So someone who comes to the site needing updated information on the topic is just out of luck?