# Asking for updated answer when original question no longer meets requirements

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic, old-questions, new-answers

On Stack Overflow I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424760/what-will-be-the-lifespan-of-the-net-framework)  which I don't believe would meet the current question requirements, I think it's too broad and off topic.

My issue is that I'd like to get an updated answer on the current life expectancy of the .NET framework.

[Another Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197691/335608) says to offer a bounty on the old question to get a new answer, which I don't think is right here.

So should I offer the bounty or is there a more suitable SE site to ask this on?

Comment: I'm afraid bounty can't make the question on topic. If what you want to ask is off topic, the simple answer is that you will simply have to ask it elsewhere, not on Stack Exchange. (If there's no other fitting site in SE, of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, this question does not meet the current question requirements of Stack Overflow. But it will not be a good question on *any* of the Stack Exchange sites; it is **primarily opinion based**:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: That's my thought, it is broad but it has been asked and answered before and not closed. So should it be flagged to close even with it being so old?

Comment: @Robert back then, the policy wasn't so strict. Yes, it should be flagged, but I have already cast a close vote so your flag will be superfluous.

Comment: I'll not flag then.